# matching escape character in R-style regex

Tags: regex, r, pcre

I am trying to write a regex that replaces all values that dont contain an `*` with `NA`. Can someone explain how to correctly negate an escape character in an R-style (PCRE?) regex?

```
temp<-data.frame(c("hi","keep**",NA),c("keep***",NA,"xxx"))
lapply(temp,function(x){gsub("[^\\*]",NA,x)}) #This did not work like I thought it would
```

GOAL

```
NA    keep***
keep* NA
NA    NA
```

Comment: Will the asterisks always be at the end of the word?

Comment: Perhaps, `lapply(temp,function(x){gsub("^[^*]*$",NA,x)})`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was exactly what I needed. Will you pose it as an answer, and explain why you used ^ twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the main issue is that you are matching only one character that is not an asterisk with `[^\\*]`, and replace it with `NA` using `gsub`, while you need to replace whole values (=strings).

Use `^[^*]*$`:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^*]*` - matches 0+ characters (due to the `*` quantifier at the end) that are not `*` (the `[^...]` is a negated character class that matches all characters other than those defined in the class)
- `$` - end of string.

Since the regex is used in `gsub` without `perl=T`, you cannot use escaped characters in the character class, it is forbidden by the TRE (derived from POSIX) regex flavor.

Answer (score 1):

The character-class operator allows negation when you make the first character "^", but since a "naked" NA is not a character value, that's not enough. You do not need to escape most otherwise special characters inside a character class sequence.  You need a different strategy to conditionally make selected items NA. For one thing you have a disguised factor-mess. I thought `ifelse` was a good strategy. R automagically makes character values into factors which cause no end of confusion. Use stringsAsFactors=FALSE or `lapply(dfrm, as.character)` to avoid or fix:

```
> temp<-data.frame(a=c("hi","keep**",NA),b=c("keep***",NA,"xxx"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> lapply(temp,function(x){ifelse( !grepl("[*]",x) , NA, x)})
$a
[1] NA       "keep**" NA      

$b
[1] "keep***" NA        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but this will also work

```
temp<-data.frame(c("hi","keep**",NA),c("keep***",NA,"xxx"))
lapply(temp,function(x){gsub("(?!.*\\*)(\\w+)", NA, x, perl=T)})
```